# Trying to get property 'categories' of non-object in

Tags: php, json

I am using json parsing in Php. i am getting all json data but ii gives error as below.

> Notice: Trying to get property 'categories' of non-object in

My codes as below

```
$json_url = "https://api.trendyol.com/sapigw/product-categories";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

   var_dump($data[0]->categories->name[0]);
```

Example Json as below.

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 368,
            "name": "Aksesuar"
        },
        {
            "id": 368,
            "name": "Aksesuar"
        }
]}
```

Comment: You have a few questions asked at this site and it looks like the answers you have received have been helpful to you. This site goes both ways. If you receive help you should reward those who help you by accepting their answer. Read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and start giving back to the community. You also get two reputation points for each accepted answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) and trying to use a flag TRUE as a second param.

`$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);` - you will get a multiply array where `$data[0]` - 'categories' and 'categories' got 2 elements which are an arrays.